# Weird white space appearing below nav bar on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, whitespace, navbar

I just finished redesigning my portfolio web site but I have one bug I can't seem to figure out. On the homepage when I hit refresh (in Chrome and Safari) a white space appears below the nav bar.

http://www.bradfordallendesign.com

This also happens when you navigate to the homepage from another page on the site. Also, I can't seem to reproduce the bug locally -- it only shows up on the live site.

Any ideas on what might cause this?

Answer (score 2):

Find and replace. Worked for `Ninja Slider v2016.12.29`

```
yb = function (d, c) {
                for (var b = [], a = 0; a < d[e]; a++)
                    b[b[e]] = String[nb](d[Z](a) - (c ? c : 3));
                if (b.join("") == "Ninja Slider trial version")
                    return "";
                return b.join("")
            },
```

Comment: Thank god!! I found you... This solution works like charm. You saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

"ninja slider trial version".

Open chrome dev tools, inspect the body, refresh multiple times, and now you can see "ninja slider trial version". Select it, delete it, and now the spacing is fixed.

Solution: purchase the slider. ;)

Comment: Crap. Okay. That explains why the issue doesn't show up locally. Thanks Michael. :) Any ideas on a free easy to implement slider? This is just a personal site -- not a commercial site.

Comment: Well. Looks like $29 was the easiest fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set the parent tag's text color property as Transparent.

```
<div style="color:transparent;">
<div id="ninja-slider" style="color:#fff">
<div class="inner">
<ul>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```